# How to store javascript value to php variable in jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, php, jqgrid

I got the row id value in my script but assign to php variable it shows object object..
How can do this?
I refer many answer but nothing will happen , I used document.write() function , its not working..

```
 <script>
        function edit()
        {
           // alert("hi");

              var id = jQuery("#list_records").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow'); 
                if (id) { 
               var ret = jQuery("#list_records").jqGrid('getRowData',id);

               var sampleedit = ret.id;
               document.cookie = "myJavascriptVar = " + sampleedit 
               alert(sampleedit); 


                 } 
                else { 
                    alert("Please select row");
                    } 
        }

        </script>
 <?php
 $servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "dbnew";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  $myPhpVar = $_COOKIE['myJavascriptVar'];
  echo $myPhpVar;

$sqlselect = "SELECT * FROM userregisterdetails ";
echo $sqlselect;
 ?>
```

Comment: PHP runs at server and JS runs at your browser, unless there is new request to server, post adding cookie by JS, your cookie won't be passed on to PHP

Comment: a JS cookie is a string, if you managed to get your cookie in server-side (which seems to be the case if you get `[object object]`), you just need to encode your JS object for it to be passed in a string, something like `JSON.stringify(sampleedit)`. Note that you won't be able to pass functions in JSON, you can pass their code, but that would require an `eval`on the other side, which is far from great